# Copy HTML table to Excel

Tags: html, css, excel

I have a table in HTML with this structure

HTML

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col1">Hello</div>
        <div class="col2">Bye</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table
{ display: table; }
.row
{ display: table-row; }
.col1, .col2 { display: table-cell; }
```

How can I copy this table to Excel? Thanks!

Comment: You can do this using JavaScript: http://wijmo.com/importing-exporting-excel-files-with-spreadjs/ or http://wsnippets.com/export-html-table-data-excel-sheet-using-jquery/ But you will need to use an actual table, I think. What you have isn't a table, but divs with class name of `table`.

Comment: Copy to Excel using what?  VBA in excel?  Code in a HTML page? Use (e.g.) `getElementsByClassName("table")(0).getElementsByClassName("row")`, then loop though that collection and either loop though the child divs of each "row" (using `rowObject.getElementsByTagName("div")` or address each "column" explicitly using `rowObject.getElementsByClassName("col"+i)`  etc etc

Answer (score -3):

You can try this web and copy the html:

[HTML to excel](http://watermark-images.com/html-to-excel-conversion.aspx)

Comment: This tool looks like it's for actual `<table>` elements only.